# How to load rows from Cassandra table as Dataframe in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I can load whole Cassandra table as dataframe as below

```
val tableDf = sparkSession.read
      .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
      .options(Map( "table" -> table, "keyspace" -> keyspace))
      .load()
```

But I couldn't find a way to fetch rows by primary key, something like

```
select * from table where key = ''
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 7):

```
val tableDf = sparkSession.read
      .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
      .options(Map( "table" -> table, "keyspace" -> keyspace))
      .load()
      .filter("key='YOUR_KEY'")
```

Using this spark-cassandra-connector will use predicate pushdown and will fetch only required data.

[Dataframes and Predicate pushdown](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/14_data_frames.md)

Answer (score 0):

Java way to the same is :

```
SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().appName("Spark Sql Job").master("local[*]")
                .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file:///c:/tmp/spark-warehouse")
                .config("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "localhost")
                .config("spark.cassandra.connection.port", "9042").getOrCreate();
        SQLContext sqlCtx = sparkSession.sqlContext();
        Dataset<Row> rowsDataset = sqlCtx.read().format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").option("keyspace", "myschema")
                .option("table", "mytable").load();
        rowsDataset.show();
```

It should be the same for scala i believe